# Why won't the bulbs light up brightly in my European chandelier?

Tags: electrical

I bought a European chandelier not knowing there were light bulb size differences. I ordered 12 European to Candelabra Reducers (E14 to E12). I was so happy when I received them, and couldn't wait to install them on my new candelabra. I installed all 12 bulbs and reducers, but to my surprise only 2 really light up and the other 10 only glow.

Can you help me and tell me what's wrong and what I need to do?

Comment: If you swap around the bulbs, does the problem track with the adapters or with the bulbs?

Comment: i'm thinking with the bulbs,not sure because i swaped both the adapters then the bulbs and still the same result

Comment: What is the voltage rating of the bulbs?  European bulbs are designed to be at full brightness at 220 volts, American standard is 120VAC.  If you are using 120 volt bulbs in the adapters they should work.

Comment: that's exactly what they are, the bulbs are 120V

Comment: There may be something about the physical configuration of the bulbs, adapters, and chandelier sockets that is preventing a positive electrical contact inside the socket, typically the center hot terminal. This problem sometimes occurs with compact fluorescent bulbs placed in old fixtures. The ceramic or cardboard tube of the socket extends too far up and contacts the bevel of the bulb base. Sometimes firmly (and carefully) screwing the bulb tighter is enough to make contact. Other times it's hopeless, one needs to find a different bulb configuration.

Comment: Another thought, sometimes the bottom center spring tab in the socket can be bent upwards enough to achieve a good electrical contact with the bulb base.

Comment: Be sure you test all 10 "glowers" in a regular lamp powered at 120 volts to be sure they really are 120 volt bulbs.

Comment: It may be the case that this chandelier was wired, or rewired, to make use of 120 volt bulbs in a 240 volt situation by wiring pairs in series.  That doesn't explain the two bright bulbs, though.  Try removing ONE of the glowing bulbs to see if another goes out ... or if the general pattern of brightness changes.

Comment: How bright does one bulb shine?

Answer (score 1):

If your bulbs ARE 120 volt and some are half lit then some are wired wrong.

They will be in series not in parallel.

To test this switch the light on and remove one bulb that is 1/2 lit. Another will go off- they are in series. Maybe even 2 will go off. They need to be re-wired in parallel.

Comment: I agree.  To me it sounds like the chandelier was rewired but never tested.   I would also wager it is not UL approved.

Answer (score 0):

240 volts is European standard
120 is U S
So, if a bulb glows brightly at 240 volts and is 60 watts, then changes in U S 
It is due to the voltage. 
240 volt 60 watt
120 volt 30 watt
See the pattern? 
Your other two that glow brighter? More than likely higher wattage than the rest. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Your math is wrong: the power used is proportional to the square of the voltage, so a European bulb used in the US would emit about 1/4 of the light, not 1/2.

Comment: @NiallC. Not to be too pedantic, but at 1/2 the voltage a bulb would use 1/4 the *power*. Actual light output for an incandescent bulb is likely to be less than 1/4, since bulbs don't have a linear relationship between power and light output.

Answer (score 0):

All replies and the OP so far seem to assume the chandelier was built for 220V. But, is there any chance this is a period piece?

Up to the 1960s (and even the early 1970s) many countries in the Mediterranean region used 230V triphase AC. This is about 120V for each individual phase, and 230V between phases. So you could wire a house using two phases to obtain 220-230V at the wall outlets for appliances, and the third phase for 120V for lighting. 120V bulbs were actually quite common in these countries.

I am starting to think you may have a chandelier wired to accept 120V bulbs, under 230V voltage; i.e. each two bulbs are placed in series.

If there is any chance the wiring is old and deteriorated by time (humidity?), I would have it remade with new material by a licensed electrician - making sure all your bulbs are connected in parallel.

HTH.

Answer (score -1):

Here several things you should know:

1st  - what is phase wire  ? do you switch it by wall switc (you need phase tester to find out) your switch should switch the phase wire (not null)

2nd such Cadelabra often have a possibility to switch only one set of lights, so you should make sure, if you have single switch, you connected together all switch wires. (should left only two wires - null and phase)

are your bulbs vacuum, neon or diod ?

this is phase indicator it should not light near the bulb places if you switch Candelabra off.
[image: phase indicator],